# Perl sequence of numbers with leading zeros

Tags: perl, sequence, leading-zero

Is there some easy way (without `sprintf` and, of course, `printf`) to get a list of `(001, 002, ... 100)` in Perl? 
In bash it was something like `seq -w 1 100`. What about Perl?

Comment: For most practical purposes `'001'..'100'` should create that list quite nicely.

Comment: Great! Didn't know that.

Comment: @evb: Please explain *why* you don't want to use `sprintf`?

Comment: @Borodin I'm used to bash's `seq -w`, so the solution with `sprintf` seems too 'heavy'. And yes, there turned out to be an even more elegant solution.

Comment: @evb sprintf / printf may seem heavy, but I've found that nearly every solution that passes through to C is faster than an pure Perl implementation, even with the overhead of the XS call.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, thanks, I'll use it in my work. I had an exam on C in 1991, but I've totally forgotten everything about the language (except that there are many curly braces). :)

Comment: @evb: It's always best to distinguish between a preference and a requirement. It may be that `sprintf` is *prohibited* for some reason, but in fact it seems that a subroutine like `sub d2 { sprintf '%02d', @_ }` would help.

Comment: @Borodin At present my goal is to know the language better. If I only used sprintf, I wouldn't have learned about '001'..'100', which is more simple. :)

Comment: @evb: It's not necessarily better to make things more simple. And that's nothing to do with distinguishing between a preference and a requirement in your questions. And as it is you have learned only a blinkered view of Perl's ability to *increment strings*. If you want to learn stuff you don't know about a language then you should read through the language reference. I still read *Programming Perl* around once a year.

Comment: @Borodin I believe that learning should be gradual and also it should be fun. If people could read a 1K-pages reference book in several days and remember it word-by-word, Q/A sites like this wouldn't probably exist. Pure imho of course and thanks again you for your help!

Comment: @evb: Your comment is still unrelated to mine: that it is important to distinguish between a preference and a requirement in your questions so that we know what we are dealing with. The main reason sites like this exist is that, even if you know the language inside-out you then have all the tools you need but may still struggle to combine them to provide a particular solution. You shouldn't think of *Stack Overflow* as a replacement for tutorials.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Somehow this came up in my notifications today.  I reread the comments, and saw something new.  First you said "faster" then you said "simple".  I think you really wanted to day "More Perl specific".  Incrementing strings isn't faster, nor is it more simple.  Perl defines "simple" in some pretty strange ways, so maybe you've drank too deeply from the Perl water.  The string increment is both slower and more complex, especially if someone slips in an unexpected character.  One problem with Perl is that it defines simple in "characters typed" instead of logic performed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
for ('001'..'100') {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

`..` in a range, returns a list of values counting by ones, from the left value to the right value.

For more details about how to use range, please refer to: 
[Perldoc range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) and [this link](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node38.html)

Comment: You might want to explain the `..` operator.

Comment: I put the reference to the documentation

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks for the links!

Comment: It's important to understand that this is a consequence of the behaviour of the `++` operator on strings, which is what the range operator `..` uses under the hood.

Comment: after I thought "how can I do that in perl" I also got it working with bash - just mention fyi: for i in {001..100};do echo ">>>${i}<<<";done`

Answer (score 6):

Printf was created for problems like this.  Using it will help you get the answers you want faster.

```
foreach my $number ( 1 .. 100 ) {
     printf "%03d\n", $number;
}
```

The `%` is the "begin a format sequence"
The `0` is "leading zeros"
The `3` is "three digits minimum"
The `d` is "treat the parameter as digits (integer)"

Comment: OP requested no `sprintf`.  Presumably that applies to `printf` as well.

Comment: I think the reason no "sprintf" has a lot to do with the Perl tutorials.  Basically, they teach formatting with "sprintf" and somehow avoid advertising in a big way that they have a "printf"  If I saw "sprintf" just so I could "print" afterwards, it would seem clunky, inelegant, and something to be avoided.

Comment: @EdwinBuck true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Probably my question was unclear, I meant to do it without either sprintf or printf.